# Not a function but function is there in solidity contract

Tags: solidity, private

I have a function called

```
function addUser(address pubkey) public {

  }
```

However when calling this function in the node backend

```
            contract.methods.addUser(address).call().then(function(result){}
```

Im getting an error saying function does not exist.

This is how the contract is being initialised:

```
const contract =  new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0xb226be108ef6fc6c60d6702ae149b290f5956377');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `call` a function which is not `view` or `pure`. Calling a method can not alter the contract´s state and your method probably wants to alter the state (I assume you just left out the implementation details). Also calling a method gives you the results directly and you can´t use a `promise` (`then`).

So you should change your `call` into `send` and add some *options* for the send (such as originating address). Also note that you will get back only a *transaction hash* instead of the actual results because the block hasn't been mined yet - but you can use the other provided events for getting the actual result. More details at: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12